# Python convert binary data (str) to match multiple of float32 size

Tags: python, string, ffmpeg, subprocess

I'm working on a tensorflow project, and I'm working with raw data from a mp3 file. I'm using `FFMPEG` and capturing `STDOUT`. `FFMPEG` outputs binary data in type `str` but it doesn't capture the data in a multiple of the size of a `float32` ...or apparently that's what I am assuming from the error I get from the following code...

```
import subprocess as sp
command = ["ffmpeg",
        '-i', image_file,
        '-f', 's16le',
        '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le',
        '-ar', '44100', # ouput will have 44100 Hz
        '-ac', '2', # stereo (set to '1' for mono)
        '-']
pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.STDOUT, stdin=sp.PIPE)
raw_audio, _  = pipe.communicate(str(88200*4).encode())
audio_array = np.fromstring(raw_audio, dtype="float32") //ERROR

dataset = np.append(dataset,audio_array)
```

**Error**

```
File "main.py", line 68, in maybe_pickle
  audio_array = np.fromstring(raw_audio, dtype="float32")
ValueError: string size must be a multiple of element size
```

`raw_audio` is in the form:

```
...7k\x01t\xf9\xc3\x01\xe3\xfa\x11\x02\xfb\xfb~\xff\x90\xfb\xbb\xfc\x83\xfa\xb4\xfd\xde\xfb\xab\xff\x01\xff\xd4\xfe:\x00T\xfd\xe0\xff\xae\xfdV\x01\xd8\xfd\x1a\x04\x0f\xfcR\x05,\xfaG\x05\xb1\xfaD\x05\xa1\xfdP\x04e\x00\xbc\x01\xe6\x00\xdf\xfe`\x00\x16\xfd\xae\x00\xec\xfc\xb7\x00\x7f\...
```

Is there a way I can truncate the data? Or maybe capture the string in an entirely different way?

Comment: Since [arguments to ffmpeg are position-dependent](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Synopsis), I assume that you checked subprocess does the right thing? If it just passes the arguments in the order you provided you have told ffmpeg to output 2 channels of 16bit signed LE PCM samples, so you should use `dtype="<i2"`. Though with stereo data the samples should also fit into 32bit floats. Can you print len(raw_audio)?

Comment: `str` is `bytes` on Python 2 i.e., it can store any number of bytes (there is no "multiple of the size" restriction). The wrong size indicates that `ffmpeg` output is not what you expect i.e., by truncating the data you would just hide the bug (get the wrong result).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian in what way is it not what the program expects?

Comment: Obviously, `ffmpeg` output is not `float32` sequence.